# Adding a path length to each node in a Binary Search Tree

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-search-tree

I have a Binary Search Tree class, and I was wondering, using the height variable, how can I use it for calculating the path length, of each individual node, from the root?

For example:

```
          S
       /     \
      E       X
     /  \
    A    H
      \    \ 
       C    M
```

The path size (height) of "E" is 1, the path size of "A" is 2, the path size of "M" is 3, the path size of "X" is 1. How would I do this at the time of inserting a node using the method put()?

```
private Key key;           // sorted by key
private Value val;         // associated data
private Node left, right;  // left and right subtrees
private int N;             // number of nodes in subtree
private int height;

private Node put(Node x, Key key, Value val)
{
    if (x == null) { return new Node(key, val, 1); }
    x.height = -1;
    int cmp = key.compareTo(x.key);

    if      (cmp < 0)
    {

        x.left  = put(x.left,  key, val);
    }
    else if (cmp > 0)
    {
        x.right = put(x.right, key, val);
    }
    else
    {
        x.val   = val;
    }
    x.N = 1 + size(x.left) + size(x.right);
    return x;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition the path to a leaf is the path to its parent + 1.

You can easily achieve that by adding to your method:

```
private Node put(Node x, Key key, Value val, int height){
 if (x == null) { return new Node(key, val, height); }
 .
 .
 .
}
```

First call to put should be `put(null,key,val,0)`

And just increment the height with each call to put for example:

```
x.left  = put(x.left,  key, val, ++height);
```

Of course you're gonna have to add height to the Node constructor.

Comment: This is the code: http://pastebin.com/5by24Lzf

It's around line 82, I also added the height to the constructor.

Comment: Sorry, wrong paste: http://pastebin.com/1gesua5W note, I forgot the remove the height++ from line 83

Comment: use ++height and not height++, pre ++ means increment then evaluate while height++ means evaluate then increment.

Comment: I fixed that, also, your if statement is not considering the N parameter.

Comment: Btw, how would I add all the heights together to get the internal path length?

Comment: Do you mean between 2 nodes?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant. But don't worry, I figured it out myself. It just took me some time.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a tree/node class relationship like the following. This gets rid of the awkward x.N = 1 + size(x.left) + size(x.right); since it doesn't make sense for a single node to have a size.

```
public class Tree<K extends Comparable<K>, V> {

  private Node head;
  private int size; // number of nodes in subtree
  private int height;

  public Node put(K key, V value) {
    size++;
    if (head == null) {
      head = new Node(key, value, 0);
      return head;
    }
    Node result = head.put(key, value);
    if (result.height > height) {
      height = result.height;
    }
    return result;
  }

  private class Node {

    private K key; // sorted by key
    private V value; // associated data
    private Node left, right; // left and right subtrees
    private int height;

    public Node(K key, V value, int height) {
      this.key = key;
      this.value = value;
      this.height = height;
    }

    private Node put(K key, V value) {
      int cmp = key.compareTo(this.key);
      if (cmp < 0) {
        if (left == null) {
          left = new Node(key, value, height + 1);
          return left;
        } else {
          return left.put(key, value);
        }
      } else if (cmp > 0) {
        if (right == null) {
          right = new Node(key, value, height + 1);
          return right;
        } else {
          return right.put(key, value);
        }
      } else {
        this.value = value;
        return this;
      }
    }
  }
}
```